# C# Dynamic database filtering with Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, linq-to-sql

I try to create generic method for filtering different entities in database in order to avoid creating huge methods for every entity with combining filtering rules using very similar if statements.

Now I'm trying to create expression which would represent equality comparison getting as parameter expression describing property to compare and some value.

My concept how to solve problem and what I created basing on other posts shows bellow code snippet:

```
public class FuelCard 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyFilter<TEntity, TProperty>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> query, 
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> expr, TProperty value)
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = param => true;

    var filterExpression = Expression.Equal(expr, Expression.Constant(value));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(filterExpression);

    predicate = predicate.And(lambda);
    return query.Where(predicate);
}
```

And in the end I would like to use it like that:

```
IQueryable<FuelCard> query = // Get cards from database as IQueryable

query = query.ApplyFilter(x => x.Id, 85);
query = query.ApplyFilter(x => x.User.LastName + " " + x.User.FirstName, "Jon Green");
```

I would like to define annonymous expressions describing how to get value of columns and then apply different filters (here is shown simple example with equal method).

But when I call Expression.Equal i got error that there is no binary operator for Func and Int32.

In the all examples there are created Expression.Parameter objects with the name of the property, but there they are operating only on properties in Entity class (without using navigation properties etc.). 
**But is it possible to combine filter expression with announymous property expression?**

I hope I described clearly what am I trying to achieve and what is the difference from the standard examples, which is source of my problems

I would be very grateful if someone help me how to create such filter in order to compare result of the expression in given in parameter with value and than apply the predicate to the query in order to run it against sql database :)

Comment: Sometimes, when your trying to create lots of complicated methods, your using the API wrong. I think that might be the case here why would you write your own "ApplyFilter" when you could just do query.where(x=> x.id == 86), query.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.LastName == "Green" && x.FirstName == "Jon") etc

Comment: @AleksAndreev I'm sorry I was changing my code to show only small piece with the problem. The ApplyFilter method was CombineQuery. I edited question and changed name to the proper one.

Comment: @chrispepper1989 But I have about 100 tables with a lot of columns in every one and I don't want to write manually such query.where(x=> x.id == 86) etc. for every get method and property.

I would like to create one generic method in order to filter with it all tables using parameters I get from client application

Comment: then you want to use Interfaces and use generic methods using interfaces, you can also use the "column" attribute to ensure that your table columns are named different to your class columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is something like:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereEqual<TSource, TProperty>(this IQueryable<TSource> query, Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertySelector, TProperty value)
{
    var body2 = Expression.Equal(propertySelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body2, propertySelector.Parameters);
    return query.Where(lambda);
}
```

Use it like:

```
IQueryable<FuelCard> query = // Get cards from database as IQueryable

query = query.WhereEqual(x => x.Id, 85);
query = query.WhereEqual(x => x.User.LastName + " " + x.User.FirstName, "Jon Green");
```

In general multiple `.Where()` are implicitly in `&&` (in *and*) between them. So you only need to create an expression based on the property selector expression plus equals plus the value passed and then return a `.Where()` that uses that expression.

Answer (score 0):

Xanatos has definitely answered your question as it was asked, but I just wanted to demonstrate some alternative ways to generalise your database tables and query statements. The first is to use a function + interfaces instead of a lambda:

```
 context.Users.Where(ReallyComplexExpression());
 private static Expression<Func<IHasName, bool>> ReallyComplexExpression()
    {
        return x =>
            x.FirstName != null && x.LastName == "Salmon" || x.FirstName == "Fish" && x.LastName == "hermonie" ||
            x.FirstName == "Thanks" && x.LastName == "for the fish";
    }
```

Another approach is generic singletons or generic static functions which do tend to behave with Linq -> SQL and often end up more readable anyway

This is very rough and not ran but it shows the basic concept:

```
public interface IHasId
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
public interface IHasName
{
    string FirstName { get;  }
    string LastName { get;  }

}
public class Employee : IHasName, IHasId
{
    [Column("Forename")] //this ensures it is still called "Forename" in the database
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Column("Surname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column("EmployeeId")]//this ensures you are following DB best practice through the same technique as above
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class User : IHasName, IHasId
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column("UserId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //equally you could add
    [notmapped]
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; 
 //or add this as an extension function for all IHasName
}

public class Job: IHasName, IHasId
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped] //not mapped tells entity framework you dont want these fields in the DB, so in the DB their would only be "name" but in your code, firstname & lastname are pseudonyms for Name 
    public string FirstName => Name;

    [NotMapped]
    public string LastName => Name;
    [Key]
    [Column("JobId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }


}

public class ModelContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}

public static class GenericExtensions
{

    public static IQueryable<TModel> GetById<TModel>(this IQueryable<TModel> db, int Id) where TModel : class, IHasId
    {
        return db.Where(x => x.Id == Id);
    }
    public static IQueryable<TModel> GetByAnyName<TModel>(this IQueryable<TModel> db, string name) where TModel : class, IHasName
    {
        return db.Where(x => x.FirstName == name || x.LastName == name);
    }
    public static IQueryable<TModel> GetByFirstAndLastName<TModel>(this IQueryable<TModel> db, string firstName, string lastName) where TModel : class, IHasName
    {
        return db.Where(x => x.FirstName == firstName && x.LastName == lastName);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ModelContext context = new ModelContext();

        var filteredEmpl =context.Employees.GetByAnyName("John").GetById(1);

        var filteredUsers =context.Users.GetByFirstAndLastName("Terry","Richards").GetById(1);

         var filteretJobs =context.Jobs.GetByAnyName("Supervisor").GetById(1); //this wouldn't work as "Name" is the DB column, so Linq->SQL would fail when confronted with "FirstName" 
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a specialisation to the job one such as " public static IQueryable<Job> GetByAnyName(this IQueryable<Job> db, string name) 
        {
            return db.Where(x => x.Name == name);
        }".

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very similar to a problem I solved. In my case, I had to filter the objects into different categories based on a complex filters that were defined in Sql syntax.

I have created a Nuget package `DynamicFilter.Sql` to dynamically generate the lambda expression from Sql.

Here is an example

```cs
var filter = FilterExpression.Compile<User>("(Age > 10) and (Name like 'Alice%' or Name like 'Bob%')");

//Filter a collection
var filteredUsers = users.Where(filter);
```

The package is open source and available on [github](https://github.com/prakashrx/DynamicFilter.Sql).