# When I retrieve GetAllAsQueryable from the repository and add a where clause, I get an error. Either rewrite the query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, repository, asqueryable

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync() {
    var dataAsQueryable = repository.GetAllAsQueryable();
    if (typeof(TenantEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) {
        var tenantId = currentUserService.GetCurrentTenantId();

        if (tenantId is null or 0) {
            return await dataAsQueryable.ToListAsync();
        }

        var tenantIdProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty("TenantId", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (tenantIdProperty != null) {
            dataAsQueryable = dataAsQueryable.Where(entity => (long)tenantIdProperty.GetValue(entity) == (long)tenantId);
        }
    }
    return dataAsQueryable;
}
```

`public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllAsQueryable() { return _dbSet.AsQueryable(); }`

TenantId cannot be null in database and type is long.
When try to get this query throwing exception like this:
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Answer (score 0):

This line cannot be translated into a sql call because of the reflection used for accessing the property:

```
dataAsQueryable = dataAsQueryable.Where(entity => (long)tenantIdProperty.GetValue(entity) == (long)tenantId);
```

If reflection is required (unlikely), then you'll have to do the filtering outside of the query:

```
dataAsQueryable = dataAsQueryable.ToArray().Where(entity => (long)tenantIdProperty.GetValue(entity) == (long)tenantId);
```

I recommend you investigate [Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814131/c-sharp-dynamic-database-filtering-with-linq-expression) to do the filtering which would allow a completely sql-side execution and maximum performance.

Comment: I solved this problem using AsEnumerable but i will try your suggestion. Thank you for answer.